# How to import and use a custom Chart.js plugin in Nuxt? (Chartjs-vuejs v2.9.4)

Tags: html, css, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I am trying to import a custom plugin into my chart.
Got this plugin from my previous question: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69642298/how-to-add-an-extra-tick-on-top-of-the-highest-bar-in-chart-js-v2-9-4-grace/69644339#69644339)
Its a plugin so that I can use Grace in my version of Chart.js.
The version of Chart.js I am using is V2.9.4.
I am using vue-chartjs in **Nuxt!**.
Couldn't really find an answer anywhere else.

[This is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAqoi.png)

[This is how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PehAM.png)

Thanks in advance. :)

1. I made a Component called 'BarChart' in my Components folder.
2. I made a normal `.vue` file in my pages directory. In the `<template>` tag I added my `<Barchart/>` component.
3. In that same `.vue` file I added a script in the `<script>` tag.
4. The plugin code is included in the codes below, I didn't include it anywhere yet.

---

1. Barchart.vue (Component)

```
    <script>
    import {Bar} from "vue-chartjs";
    
    export default {
      extends: Bar,
      props: {
        data: {
          type: String,
          default: () => {},
        },
        options: {
          type: Object,
          default: () => {},
        },
      },
      computed: {
        Chart() {
          return['data', 'options'];
        },
      },
      mounted() {
        this.renderChart(this.data, this.options);
      },
    };
    </script>
```

2. .vue file (Include component)

```
    <div class="chart">
      <BarChart :data="barChartData" :options="barChartOptions" :height="200"/>
    </div>
```

3. .vue file (script tags)

```
    <script>
    import BarChart from "~/components/plugins/BarChart";
    
    export default {
      components: {
        BarChart,
      },
      data() {
        return {
          barChartData: {
            labels: ["Verzonden", "Ontvangen", "Geopend", "Kliks"],
            datasets: [
              {
                data: [25, 20, 20, 18],
                backgroundColor: [
                  '#7782FF',
                  '#403DD3',
                  '#FFB930',
                  '#00E437',
                ],
                barThickness : 50,
              },
            ],
          },
          barChartOptions: {
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
              display: false,
            },
            scales: {
              xAxes: [
                {
                  gridLines: {
                    display: false,
                  },
                  ticks: {
                    fontColor: "black",
                    fontSize: 14,
                  },
                },
              ],
              yAxes: [
                {
                  ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    min: 0,
                    stepSize: 5,
                    fontColor: '#ABACB3',
                  },
                  gridLines: {
                    display: true,
                    borderDash: [4, 4],
                    color: '#EEEDFB',
                    drawBorder: false,
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        };
      },
    };
    </script>
```

4. Plugin code (where do I put this and how do I make it work?)

```
    const plugin = {
      id: "customScale",
      beforeLayout: (chart, options, c) => {
        let max = Number.MIN_VALUE;
        let min = Number.MAX_VALUE
        let grace = options.grace || 0
    
        chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
          max = Math.max(max, Math.max(...dataset.data));
          min = Math.min(min, Math.min(...dataset.data))
        })
    
        if (typeof grace === 'string' && grace.includes('%')) {
          grace = Number(grace.replace('%', '')) / 100
    
          chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMax = max + (max * grace)
          chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMin = min - (min * grace)
    
        } else if (typeof grace === 'number') {
    
          chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMax = max + grace
          chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMin = min - grace
    
        }
    
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [vue-chartjs documentation](https://vue-chartjs.org/api/#addplugin) you can do this in 2 ways.

If you want the plugin to be available for all your charts you can use the global registration like so:

```js
import Chart from 'chart.js'

Chart.pluginService.register({
    id: "customScale",
    beforeLayout: (chart, options, c) => {
      let max = Number.MIN_VALUE;
      let min = Number.MAX_VALUE
      let grace = options.grace || 0

      chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        max = Math.max(max, Math.max(...dataset.data));
        min = Math.min(min, Math.min(...dataset.data))
      })

      if (typeof grace === 'string' && grace.includes('%')) {
        grace = Number(grace.replace('%', '')) / 100

        chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMax = max + (max * grace)
        chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMin = min - (min * grace)

      } else if (typeof grace === 'number') {

        chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMax = max + grace
        chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMin = min - grace

      }

    }
  });
```

This way of importing and registering should work from anywhere in your app.

The second way is an inline plugin. This needs to be done in your `BarChart.vue` and goes like this:

```js
mounted() {
  this.addPlugin(
    Chart.pluginService.register({
      id: "customScale",
      beforeLayout: (chart, options, c) => {
        let max = Number.MIN_VALUE;
        let min = Number.MAX_VALUE
        let grace = options.grace || 0

        chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
          max = Math.max(max, Math.max(...dataset.data));
          min = Math.min(min, Math.min(...dataset.data))
        })

        if (typeof grace === 'string' && grace.includes('%')) {
          grace = Number(grace.replace('%', '')) / 100

          chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMax = max + (max * grace)
          chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMin = min - (min * grace)

        } else if (typeof grace === 'number') {

          chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMax = max + grace
          chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.suggestedMin = min - grace

        }

      }
    });
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaction.   I am trying to make it global, so I added it as your first option.  
I get a few errors back from Phpstorm: Unresolved var grace, unused parameter c.
Also in my browser it says: typerror: cannot read property 'register' of undefined.

Sorry for the questions, I am a beginner in this stuff and I am not that good in JS etc.

Comment: Chart.js v2 does not have any typing so you must rely on the `@types/chart.js` package so if they havent typed it you must type ignore it since it does work (might have typed it under `Chart.plugins.register()` but I expect if they didnt type the first way they also didnt do it the second way). The C variable can indeed be removed from the function declaration. Only thing I can think of why grace is undefined is because your editor doesnt see the config plugins object so you will need to just ignore that

Comment: How do I type ignore it?

Comment: You can comment  [`// @ts-ignore`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) above it

Comment: I tried that, doesn't work :/